# if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') working with Chrome but not Safari

Tags: python, django, https, safari, http-referer

I have the following function redirecting users if they have not come to the page from a Stripe checkout. The page will load if coming from a checkout on google chrome but if using safari on laptop on IOS it will redirect. Is there a way I can fix this to work on safari? -

```
def register(request):
    if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == "https://checkout.stripe.com/":
        return render(request, 'users/register.html')
    else:
        return redirect('error')
```

I also have the settings for my site as SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "no-referrer-when-downgrade"

Comment: This does not only depend on the browser, but mainly on the privacy settings. You can never control what the browser will send, so you should not assume that this will contain any data.

Comment: Is there a reason that it would not be working on Safari though as it works on Google Chrome everytime?

Comment: you can block this on Google Chrome as well https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin Furthermore you can "forge" this. As in, with `wget` one can send a HTTP request with a totally different referrer. It is thus simply something a client sends, and you can not make any assumption regarding *if* it will send that, and if it is genuine